# Unable to connect to google VM

Tags: google

Got email this morning from Google -  Important: your trial has ended. It’s time to upgrade

Upgrade to paid account, but the website still not reachable.

Try ping the IP address or on browser, keep got time out.

Any idea, pease?

Answer (score 0):

Your resources (such as virtual machine instances) are stopped when your free trial ends, and you had not upgraded your account.

After upgrading your account, you simply need to restart them.